# Group Strings by matching pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm looking for a way to group Strings (e.g. in an array) if they have a matching pattern.
For example I have an associative array with these strings as keys:

```
1111567
1111568
1111608
2222345
2222495
```

Now I want to iterate trough the array of strings and group all '1111', '2222' and so on.

Comment: Do you want to test ALLWAYS the 4 first characters? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(((\d)\3{1,})\d+(?:(?:\n|$)\2\d+)*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture 1 or group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/70

```
$re = "/(((\\d)\\3{1,})\\d+(?:(?:\\n|$)\\2\\d+)*)/i";
$str = "1111567\n1111568\n1111608\n2222345\n2222495";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Great site, thanks for that. The problem is that the matching patterns don't always have the same size. Sometimes the first 4 chars are matching, sometimes 5 or 6 or 3.

Comment: Nearly :) I think my example data were a bit to general. Here is a more detailed strings:
7734506
7734516
91011504
91011505
91011506
91011510
91011503
91011500
91011502
91011501
9101100
91175505
91175506
91175503
91175518
91175507
91175500
91175501
9117500
91010518
91010519
91174506
91174503
91174518
91174507
91174509

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but how about:

```
$arr = array(
    '1111567' => 'a',
    '1111568' => 'b',
    '1111608' => 'c',
    '2222345' => 'd',
    '2222495' => 'e',
);
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    preg_match('/^(\d{4})/', $k, $m);
    $res[$m[1]] .= $v;
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1111] => abc
    [2222] => de
)
```

Comment: [Here's how I understood it](https://eval.in/277650), this is similar.